# Как правильно составить MySQL-запрос?

Tags: mysql

В БД MySQL есть 2 таблицы (фотографии и комментарии к ним):

```
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
  `photo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `photo_title` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`photo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `photo_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment_text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Требуется составить SQL-запрос, который выведет список фотографий, с указанием количества комментариев, отсортированные в порядке убывания их количества, у которых меньше 5 пользователей-комментаторов.

Comment: @Pferdeficker, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: В том и проблема - я даже не знаю, как подступиться к решению задачи.

Comment: разделите задачу на несколько. напишите запрос на каждую часть, потом соедините их join'ами. сортировки можно добиться вложенным запросом.

Answer (score 1):

Если не обращать внимания на возможный случай, когда пользователь может оставлять более одного комментария, то получается такой запрос:

```
    SELECT c.photo_id,
           p.photo_title,
           count(c.comment_id) AS comments_counter
      FROM comments AS c
INNER JOIN photos AS p ON p.photo_id = c.photo_id
  GROUP BY c.photo_id
    HAVING comments_counter < 5
  ORDER BY comments_counter DESC
```

[Демо на SQLfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e523f/5/0).

В качестве первого шага посоветую присмотреться к вкладке *"Поиск"* в PhpMyAdmin. Конструируете запрос, смотрите, что получилось, корректируете.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(c.comment_id) as count_photos, COUNT(DISTINCT c.user_id) as count_users 
FROM `photos` as p 
LEFT JOIN comments as c ON (c.photo_id=p.photo_id) 
GROUP BY p.photo_id 
HAVING count_users > 5 
ORDER BY count_photos DESC
```